# Words in text counter. Speed up function

Tags: python-3.x, counter

Please find below my function `words_in_text_counter(in_text,frequency=2)`. It accepts a text and returns a list of all words which occur with a required frequency (default frequency is 2). It works well, but gets too slow with large texts. Where can this function be improved to speed searches in larger texts?

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def words_in_text_counter(in_text,frequency=2):
    no_noise_text = re.sub(r'[0-9.,:;<>"#!%&/()=?*-+]','',in_text.lower()).strip().split()

    frequency_dict = {}
    for key, value in Counter(no_noise_text).items():
        frequency_dict.setdefault(value, []).append(key)

    try:
        print(str(frequency)+' times words in text.')
        return frequency_dict[frequency]
    except KeyError:
        return str(frequency)+' times never happens in text.'
```

Comment: If the code works without any problems, it may better fit on [codereview.se]: "Code Review Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews." That said, you may want to add what the 'large text' is where you run into problems: 100 words? 1000? More than a million? You may also be able to profile your program and pinpoint where exactly it slows down.

Comment: You should profile your code to find out, where you spend most of your runtime. I would recommend line_profiler (https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) for this. you will find a nice tutorial on the web page. That said, your runtime problem is `(char for char in in_text.lower() if char in letters)` which is really hard to optimize. I would write that as an answer, but 1) I didn't find a faster way of doing this and 2) as @Jongware pointed out, this would better fit CodeReview than Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks @Jongware, will follow your advise